# asp.net object moved

Tags: java, asp.net, http-post

```
String parameters = "__VIEWSTATE=" + "__EVENTTARGET="
                + "__EVENTARGUMENT=" + "&ctl00$tbUsername="
                + URLEncoder.encode("name", "UTF-8") + "&ctl00$tbPwd="
                + URLEncoder.encode("pssw", "UTF-8")
                + "&ctl00$chkRememberLogin=" + URLEncoder.encode("0", "UTF-8")
                + "&ctl00$cmdLogin=" + URLEncoder.encode("Login", "UTF-8");
    URL url;
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    try {
        url = new URL("www.website.com/Login.aspx");
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                "text/html; charset=utf-8");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length",
                "" + Integer.toString(parameters.getBytes().length));
//trying everything..
        connection.setDefaultUseCaches(true);
        connection.setUseCaches(true);

        connection.setUseCaches(true);
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setAllowUserInteraction(true);
        connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
        HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(true);

        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(
                connection.getOutputStream());
        wr.writeBytes(parameters);
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (connection != null) {
            connection.disconnect();
        }

    }
}
```

and here is a HTML form

```
<form id="LoginForm" name="LoginForm" method="post" action="Login.aspx?__ufps=747201&loggedout">
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEXAQUDX19QD2QPBirKUk9SFs6IZg==">
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" value="">
<script language=javascript><!--
function __doPostBack(target, argument){
  var theform = document.LoginForm
  theform.__EVENTTARGET.value = target
  theform.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = argument
  theform.submit()
}
// -->
</script>

<div nowrap><b>Username:</b></div><input name="ctl00$tbUsername" /><br>
<b>Password:</b><br>
<input name="ctl00$tbPwd" type="password"/><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="ctl00$chkRememberLogin" value="0" checked>Remember Me<br>
<input name="ctl00$cmdLogin" type="submit" value="Login"/>&nbsp;
                        <input name="ctl00$cmdForgetMe" type="submit" value="Forget Me"/>
</form>
```

The reply message is: "Object moved to here". #%^#%^?! Can somebody explain what could possibly be wrong... WireShark showing the same post requests from both client and browser

P.S. People who knows, please help..

Comment: I do not understand the problem. Does the HTML form work?

Comment: yes, the html form works, the problem is that i am probably using the wrong method for posting data to the service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand you try to send via post the name and password **and you get a redirect message** ! from the web page that say to you to read a different location.

This is because of

1. You try an unsecured page and server redirect you to a secure SSL.
2. After your post, the server proceed the data and response with a redirect to a new page.

Comment: You understand it totally right. when i try to use another method for post, i just get the page where i want to make post without the values

Comment: the second case: when server redirects, shouldn't connection.followredirects(true) solve this problem?

Comment: is there another way for authorisation in SSL?

Comment: @Mocialov probably the followredirect can solve the problem, but actually there is no problem - you just get a response that you need to react.

Comment: also when I get this "object moved" message, the link is like: www.website.com/Login.aspx?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1   from which i assume that server wants me to enable cookies.. or is it wrong? should i just redirect request myself?

Comment: P.S. web service is not written by me